# Whole div is replaced while trying to replace an element

Tags: javascript

I want to replace an element by another.
The element however is placed in an div with other elements.
When I run my code the whole div is replaced.
How do I prevent this behavior?

```
function edit(e) {
   selectedElement = e.id
   var newElement = document.createElement("input");
   var newElementA = document.createTextNode("bla");
   newElement.appendChild(newElementA);
   var oldElement = document.getElementById(selectedElement);
   var parentDiv = oldElement.parentNode
   parentDiv.replaceChild(newElement, oldElement);
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what this has to do with "bubbling".

Comment: Oh, also, you can't put a text node in an `<input>` element; they have an empty content model.

Comment: Thought is was :(  (I will edit the subject)

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), or at least a full code snippet which reproduces your issue would be wellcome.

Comment: The thing is. I'd like to change the text of an `<a>` element by clicking it. upon clicking it an inputbox should appear with the same text as the `<a>` element in it, for the user to adjust it. After exiting the inputbox the adjusted text should be changed back in a `<a>` element with the adjusted text. My first step was trying to get the input box for the user to adjust the text.

Comment: In the JavaScript, `e` is the same as `oldElement`, is that right?

Comment: @MrLister that's right

Comment: Your script is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4tL3zj2e/). Please  post html as well just in case we are missing out anything.

Comment: @KingSize It seems to work indeed. I have to take a look in my code where it goes wrong

Comment: I found the problem `<div id="output" onclick="edit(this)">
</div>` it used the same onclick event in the `div` thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be appending a text node to an input box. You should set the value.

[Here is a working codepen, based on your comments.](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/OyJZKe)

```
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div>
    hi
  </div>
  <a id="pleaseReplace" onclick="edit(event)">hi2</a>
  <div>
    hi3
  </div>
</div>


function edit(e) {
  selectedElement = document.getElementById(e.srcElement.id);
  var newElement = document.createElement("input");
  newElement.value = selectedElement.innerHTML;
  var parentDiv = selectedElement.parentNode
  selectedElement = parentDiv.replaceChild(newElement, selectedElement);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to set the value rather than appending a text node. Got it working now!